# How do I increase numDigits without making the method non-static?

Tags: java, class, data-structures, static, instantiation

There's three pieces of the code I was given in my BigInteger homework that requires us to store, as the name suggests, integers of extreme size into linked lists, given a String input.

If given a string "0054321" the resulting linked list will store 1->2->3->4->5 in positional order, disregarding insignificant digits.

But as I try to traverse through the string, I am trying to increment numDigits by 1 each time I find a significant digit.

BigInteger.java (The code I'm working on right now)

```
package bigint;
import sun.security.x509.InvalidityDateExtension;

public class BigInteger {

    boolean negative;
    int numDigits;
    DigitNode front;

    public BigInteger() {
        negative = false;
        numDigits = 0;
        front = null;
    }

    public static BigInteger parse(String integer)
    throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        this.front = new DigitNode(1, null);
        int length = integer.length();
        while (length > 0 && a <= length) {
            if (integer.charAt(a) == '-') {
                this.negative = true;
                a++;
            }
            if (integer.charAt(a) == ' ' && this.numDigits == 0) {
                a++;
            }
            if (integer.charAt(a) == ' ' && this.numDigits == 0) {
                a++;
                continue;
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(integer.charAt(a))) {
                if(integer.charAt(a) == ' ' && this.numDigits == 0) {
                    a++;
                    continue;
                }
                this.numDigits = this.numDigits + 1;

            }

            /* IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD */
        }
        // following line is a placeholder for compilation
        return null;
    }
```

DigitNode.java (The class that encapsulates the linked list, NOT ALLOWED TO EDIT THIS)

```
package bigint;
public class DigitNode {

    int digit;
    DigitNode next;

    DigitNode(int digit, DigitNode next) {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return digit + "";
    }
}
```

BigTest.java (The tester class that tests whether the parse/add/multiply methods word, NOT ALLOWED TO EDIT THIS)

```
package bigint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigTest {

    static Scanner sc;

    public static void parse() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\tEnter integer => ");
        String integer = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.parse(integer);
            System.out.println("\t\tValue = " + bigInteger);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("\t\tIncorrect Format");
        }
    }

    public static void add() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\tEnter first integer => ");
        String integer = sc.nextLine();
        BigInteger firstBigInteger = BigInteger.parse(integer);

        System.out.print("\tEnter second integer => ");
        integer = sc.nextLine();
        BigInteger secondBigInteger = BigInteger.parse(integer);

        BigInteger result = BigInteger.add(firstBigInteger,secondBigInteger);
        System.out.println("\t\tSum: " + result);
    }

    public static void multiply() 
    throws IOException {
        System.out.print("\tEnter first integer => ");
        String integer = sc.nextLine();
        BigInteger firstBigInteger = BigInteger.parse(integer);

        System.out.print("\tEnter second integer => ");
        integer = sc.nextLine();
        BigInteger secondBigInteger = BigInteger.parse(integer);

        BigInteger result = BigInteger.multiply(firstBigInteger,secondBigInteger);
        System.out.println("\t\tProduct: " + result);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        char choice;
        while ((choice = getChoice()) != 'q') {
            switch (choice) {
                case 'p' : parse(); break;
                case 'a' : add(); break;
                case 'm' : multiply(); break;
                default: System.out.println("Incorrect choice"); 
            }
        }
    }

    private static char getChoice() {
        System.out.print("\n(p)arse, (a)dd, (m)ultiply, or (q)uit? => ");
        String in = sc.nextLine();
        char choice;
        if (in == null || in.length() == 0) {
            choice = ' ';
        } else {
            choice = in.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
        return choice;
    }

}
```

However, I get the errors of:

java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context,

For any this.numDigits or this.front or this.negative.

Whenever I try to increase numDigits, or change the value of the integer to positive, it happens. Somebody please help, Data Structures is really kicking my butt right now.

Comment: As you are calling from a static method, the fields will need to also be static

Comment: As others have highlighted, the issue is that your static methods cannot access your instance variables `negative`, `numDigits` and `front`.   Instead of simply slapping `static` on the declarations, what you need to do now is to decide what variables are part of defining what a BigInteger *IS*, and which are simply artefacts of the `parse`, etc operations.   The latter variables you would move from the instance, and into the appropriate methods.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance that is calling a method. Static methods do not have an associated instance (generally shouldn't be called from an instance at all), and therefore there is no `this` instance.

However, you can create an instance inside of your static method and affect *its* fields, for example:

```
public static BigInteger parse(String integer)
throws IllegalArgumentException {
    BigInteger parsedBI = new BigInteger();
    //...
    parsedBI.front = new DigitNode(1, null);
    //...
    parsedBI.numDigits = parsedBI.numDigits + 1;
    //...
}
```

Also (I'm one to talk as an SO noob myself), [avoid giving more code in your questions than is needed (minimal reproducible example).](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've got a downvote, which is fine, but I'd be most thankful if someone could tell me where I misstepped.

Comment: I don't even have the power to downvote, haha. Thank you so much, it cleared it up. I'm really bad with Data Structures and I'm trying to learn and I've been stuck at this step for ages.

Comment: Don't fret, just stick with it and things will click in time. When keywords like `static`, `const`, etc..., are jammed into your code, be sure you understand/look-up exactly what they do. Otherwise, you'll end up with confusing results like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static BigInteger parse(String integer)
```

The `parse` method is defined as a static function, so it doesn't have access to any `BigInteger` instance. "`this`" is meaningless. No instance has been created yet.

You could create a new `BigInteger` instance inside of `parse` method. That object would then have access to its instance variables like numDigits.

```
bi = new BigInteger()
```

Then you can access `bi.numDigits` rather than `this.numDigits` which doesn't make sense. Here `bi` points to an object instance of BigInteger whereas `this` doesn't point to anything because we're not inside an instance, we're in a static method.

Think of the static `parse` method as just a helper function that in theory could've resided somewhere outside the class definition, but is inside the class definition for convenience and clarity. Its job is to create a `BigInteger` instance by parsing text.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly the fix that was needed. <3

Comment: Glad it helped... an upvote would be appreciated if possible... thanks!